# Is it allowed to use "equal to" and "approximately equal to" in the same sentence?

Tags: arithmetic

Let's use the following example:

$$17! = 16!*17 \approx 2 \cdot 10^{13} * 17 = 3.4 \cdot 10^{14} $$

Are you allowed to do this? I am in doubt whether or not this indicates that $17! = 3.4 \cdot 10^{14}$, which is obviously not true, but I think it doesn't.

Comment: If I were to write $3 < 3+1 = 4$, would you deduce that $3=4$?

Comment: It's fine. $a=b\approx c=d$ means that $a=b, b\approx c, $ and $c=d$. It does not mean that $a=d$.

Comment: If you're confused, always add parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example claims that two things are equal (on the left), two things are equal (on the right), and that the left pair are approximately equal to the right pair.

One should be careful with too much use of the ill-defined $\approx$ symbol, or you can get $$1\approx 1.01\approx 1.02\approx \cdots \approx 1.99\approx 2$$

Comment: And all those claims are correct.

Comment: I disagree. It is legitimate to use it that way, just as one can write (for example) $5\cdot7=35>30=5\cdot6$. This notation is often used in more complex proofs.

Comment: @barakmanos, the $>$ symbol is well-defined and transitive; with what are you disagreeing?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed. It is like asking: does
$$10 = 5*2 \geq 5$$
indicate that $10=5$?